# Estoy creando una aplicacion pero me dice que es obsoleto mi codigo?

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Lo que pasa es que he copiado de este video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFS-wfz9Nb4) el codigo y todo me he fijado que es del 2017 y sabia que podia fallar pero pues lo intente, segui todo como lo hacer pero al final al querer usar el emulador me dice esto:

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'implementation' and 'api'.

que tengo 5 errores

Comment: Para empezar la etiqueta debe ser android, no javascript. Que muestra el logCat? Muestra el código del gradle (app)

Comment: Si eso dije despues xD perdon me equivoque. En seguida comento el codigo

Comment: Ammm espero que sea este el codigo gradle (app) aqui lo queria comentar pero no me dejo esta largo asi que lo puse en mi google plus le dejo el link para que pueda verlo ( https://plus.google.com/115413650822843498915/posts/dpkhYcv27mt ). Le pido perdon por mi ignorancia, es que soy principiante. Muchas gracias por responder en verdad

Comment: Bueno tenia un poco de idea que estaria mal mi codigo, porque lo copie tal cual del video que cito en la pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es bien sencillo, lo unico que tienes que hacer es que en app/build.gradle en la sección *dependencies* debes cambiar todo tus liberias que dicen compile y poner implementation. Te dejo de ejemplo mi seccion dependencies.

```
dependencies {

    //TODO comienza con implementation antes decia compile
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    //Support
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

    //Zxing
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'

    //Easy Permissions
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.3.0'

    // Reactive
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.3"

    //itextPDF
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.0.6'
}
```

Ademas, agrega lo siguiente en tu clase ResetPasswordActivity

en la sección imports

```
import erwinavendaomiguelgijon.gihac0m.R
```

Sobre el problema del emulador podrias revisar esta respuesta.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82966/discussion-on-answer-by-carlosgub-estoy-creando-una-aplicacion-pero-me-dice-que).

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys como se pueden hacer convesasiones como chat?

Comment: El mismo sistema te lo sugiere cuando se extiende la conversación  @Carlosgub

Comment: Gracias, para la proxima lo hare :D